# how to show api data with angularJs in html

Tags: angularjs

Hello i have the following code and i want to show the objects that the api returns in to my html but i am drawing a blank on this, also i want to make a filter to sort by `id`.

```
angular.module('MainApp').controller('PhoneController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.home = "This is the homepage";

    $scope.getRequest = function () {
        console.log("I've been pressed!");
        $http.get("http://api.myjson.com/bins/12qiaa")
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.response = response;
                console.log(response.data.galerija);
                var row0 = response.data.galerija[0];
                var row1 = response.data.galerija[1];
                var row2 = response.data.galerija[2];
                var row3 = response.data.galerija[3];
                var row4 = response.data.galerija[4];
                var row5 = response.data.galerija[5];
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("Unable to perform get request");
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate your html you will have to bind your modal to the view. Angular uses [handlebar](https://handlebarsjs.com/) syntax.

First thing is to declare your model, let's say `$scope.galerijas`, then after your `$http` GET request you will populate response to your `$scope.galerijas` model.

Finally we will use  [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop over `$scope.galerijas` and bind it to the view. A filter `|` is used to order the displayed results by id.

Sample Html

```
<div ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="PhoneController">
  <h2>{{ home }}</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in galerijas | orderBy:'id'"> 
      <figure class="figure">
        <img src="{{ x.slika }}" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="{{ x.naziv }}">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right">{{ x.naziv }}</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="button" ng-click="getRequest()">Get Galerija</button>
</div>
```

Sample Script

```
var app = angular.module("MainApp", []);
app.controller("PhoneController", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.home = "This is the homepage";
  $scope.galerijas = []; // This will hold all our galerija after ajax request;

  $scope.getRequest = function() {
    console.log("I've been pressed!");
    $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/12qiaa")
      .then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data.galerija);
        $scope.galerijas = response.data.galerija; // populate from api;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Unable to perform get request");
      });

    console.log($scope.galerijas);
  }
});
```

And here is an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbxmfarz/3/